# Receiving SQL Object Already named 'x' in the DB, Even after dropping

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#TempTableHoldingRepairsList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempTableHoldingRepairsList
    GO

SELECT 
a.EnteredDate,
bb.EmployeeId,
bb.EmployeeName,
dd.EquipmentId,
dd.EquipmentName,
ee.PK_WorkOrder,
StatusName = 'NOT-SERVICEABLE'

INTO #TempTableHoldingRepairsList

FROM dbo.PIT_Inspection a

INNER JOIN dbo.PIT_EmployeeName bb
ON a.FK_EmployeeName = bb.PK_EmployeeName

INNER JOIN dbo.PIT_EquipmentName dd
ON a.FK_EquipmentName = dd.PK_EquipmentName

LEFT JOIN dbo.PIT_WorkOrder ee
ON ee.FK_EmployeeName = bb.PK_EmployeeName

WHERE a.FK_Status = 2

GROUP BY ee.PK_WorkOrder, a.EnteredDate, bb.EmployeeId, bb.EmployeeName, dd.EquipmentId, dd.EquipmentName
GO

--Now Count how many work orders for each.
SELECT COUNT(*) AS WorkOrderCount FROM PIT_WorkOrder pw 
INNER JOIN #TempTableHoldingRepairsList th
ON th.PK_WorkOrder = pw.PK_WorkOrder
```

Not sure if I'm doing the final inner join wrong or missing something completely, but I continue to receive:

`There is already an object named '#TempTableHoldingRepairsList' in the database.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check for the existence of a temporary table directly they way you're doing it.  You need to look in tempdb.  You need to change the check to the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTableHoldingRepairsList') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempTableHoldingRepairsList
    GO
```

Comment: Thanks, That did it :)